# Logistic regression with weighted data (population)

Tags: r, warnings, logistic-regression, weighted

Im trying to run a logistic regression for data that have been collected through a real survey. The dataset containts aggregated data (i.e. have been derived as the sum of microdata) and has the following columns:

1. a dependent Y variable about the existence of a characteristic (binary: 0,1)
2. three explanatory categorical variables, i.e. sex, age groups and level of education
3. a value in thousands, after applying weighting adjustments in the survey respondents that reflects the sample frequencies at the population level.
4. frequencies, i.e. the number of persons in the sample that have the specific characteristics (e.g. number of female persons in the sample aged 15-34, with level 1 of educational attainment that have the characteristic).

Thus, I have all the possible combinations of demographic variables  (all categorical) for a Y dependent variable (0,1) for 10 countries.More specifically, you can see the format of my dataset if you run the following:

```
Country<-rep(c(paste("country",1:10,sep='_',each=36)
Y<-rep(0:1, each=18, len=360)
Sex<- rep(c("Females", "Males"), each=9, times=20)
Age<- rep(c("15-34", "35-54", "55+"), each=3, times=40)
Education<- rep(c("edu1", "edu2", "edu3"), len=360)
Value<- runif(360, 0.6, 100.56)
Freq<- floor(runif(360,1,150)) 

data<- data.frame(Country, Y, Sex, Age, Education, Value, Freq)
```

After a lot of research, I chose to run the logistic regression firstly, as following:

```
glm(Y~Age+Sex+Education+Country, weights=Value, data=data, family=binomial(logit))
```

But i had an error - warning message:

```
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

Then I reshaped my data from long to wide form in order to run a second  logistic, as:

```
glm( cbind(ans1,ans0) ~ Age+Sex+Education+Country,  data=data, family = binomial(logit))
```

But I have also an error - warning message:

```
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : non-integer counts in a binomial glm!
```

The results of both ways are completely different when there are NAs in some combinations of categories.

So, I would appreciate if anyone could answer any of the questions below:

1. does anybody knows if I am running glm correctly with the first or the second way? My problem is that I do not know whether I can run the logistic regression with weighted data. Should I use for example the frequencies from the sample? But then I do not have the weights used...
2. why I have different results from the two ways when there NAs in the explanatory variable?
3. when I run the glm with the value in thousands or and the actual value, i.e. multiplied by 1000, I have the same ORs but different Standard Errors, deviance, AIC etc. Which is correct? Is it wrong if I use the population in thousands?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a problem with your Shift + i key?

Comment: You should provide some reproducible example of your data. From nothing, I can only imagine that you are only giving a positive weight to cases where Y == 1. Perhaps 'cbind(ans1,ans0)' removes all variation in the response variable. But this is a shoot in  the dark here. Your specification for  the weight parameter is fine. You can include whatever you want there as long as the vector reflects your data properly, like: POPULATION * wt.

Comment: I've just edited my question and i wish my problem is more clear to you!